# Force hardspace in multiple citations

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, citing, widows-orphans

To cite multiple references, I'm using `\cite{foo, bar}`. Unfortunately, the second citation appears on a new page. Is there a way to force a hardspace between the two citations?

This is primarily a problem because a new section begins on page 29:
[image]

Comment: If the last line of a paragraph starts a new page, that lne is referred to as "widow"; see questions tagged with [tag:widows-orphans].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a one-off final editing correction rather than changing the setting of all such citations you could use `\mbox{\cite{foo,bar}}` But I doubt there is enough flexibility in the shown line to find good line and page break in that case.

It might be better (if re-wording isn't an option) to allow the line to break there but use

```
\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}
```

To allow the `45]` to stay on the page (on an extra line) and the section to start the next page. As the line is so short it won't interfere with the page number.

Comment: +1 for teaching me `\enlargethispage` - great to know!